# How do I solve this equation in terms of Bessel's functions? $xy'' + y = 0, \ x > 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

My current progress is using the standard equation $xy'' + cy' + k^2(x^r) y = 0$, and I get $c = 0, r = 0, m = 1, a = 1/2$. But I am not sure what my next step should be or whether this is correct. Could anyone kindly help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of your equation is $$c_1 \sqrt{x} J_1\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)+2 i c_2 \sqrt{x} Y_1\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right).$$
In order to get the standard Bessel equation with a linear argument, its evident that you have to substitute the independent variable $x=w^2$ with $$\partial_{x,x}y(x^2) = 2 y'(x^2) +4 x^2 \ y''(x^2)$$
The number of different forms of linear ODE's of second order yielding Bessel functions as solutions is two pages with 34 entries in Gradshteyn/Rhyzik 8.49

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! may I ask why there is an $i$ in the solution? meanwhile I'll also read the Gradshteyn/Rhyzik.

Comment: The imgaginary i is irrelevant, it multiplies the free constant $c:_2$ and is produced by taking the square root $\sqrt(-x)$, probably by some  resubstitution formalism